# FreeRTOS, Eclipse IDE, and Syntax Errors

Tags: c, eclipse, syntax, freertos

I have a slight annoyance when dealing with FreeRTOS code in Eclipse and I'm not sure if it's just me or if other people have this issue too but I see a lot of syntax errors highlighted in my code but it compiles/executes fine. The syntax errors seem to be caused by FreeRTOS specific code like:

```
signed portCHAR *x;
```

or

```
vSemaphoreCreateBinary (semaphore);
```

or

```
signed portBASE_TYPE gpsTaskStart (void)
{
  return xTaskCreate (vGPSTask, (const signed portCHAR * const) "GPS", configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE, NULL, (tskIDLE_PRIORITY + 1), &taskHandles [TASKHANDLE_GPS]);
}
```

I was wondering if there was a way to configure Eclipse to parse this syntax properly.

Comment: what exactly is the error? it doesn't parse the portCHAR, portBASE_TYPE corerctly?

Comment: Eclipse highlights the entire line as a syntax error. It goes through gcc just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just have to update your Eclipse project configuration for the incremental checker to be able to find FreeRTOS symbol definitions.

Right click on your project > Properties > C/C++ General > Path and Symbols > Includes.
Add the FreeRTOS folder there.

Answer (score 0):

Go to project settings > directories and include all directories containing .h files (including portable/GCC/%yourplatform%). Once done, make a build. This should work, at least works for me.